# jQuery UI cant filter with external JSON file - list all items

Tags: json, jquery-ui, filter, external

My ext. JSON(cant be edited):

```
{
  "1": {
    "name":"Mr. Nicholas Van Orton",
    "discount":5,
    "tax":1,
    "pic":"1.jpg"
  },
  "2": {
    "name":"Jessie Klod",
    "discount":3,
    "tax":0,
    "pic":"2.jpg"
  },
  "3": {
    "name":"John Smith",
    "discount":0,
    "tax":0,
    "pic":""
  }  
}
```

My jQueryUI autocomplete:

```
$('.tables .new_bill .client').autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.getJSON("data/clients.json", function (data) {
            response($.map(data, function (item) {
                return {
                    label: item.name,
                    value: item.name,
                    pic: item.pic
                };
            }));
            response($.ui.autocomplete.filter(array, request.term));
        });
    },
    minLength: 0,
});
```

And whatever I type always get full list of my ext JSON object in autocomplete dropdown...

Answer (score 0):

I found this way:

```
$.getJSON("data/clients.json", function (data) {
    clients=data;
    var clients_ar=[];
    $.each(data, function(k,v) {
        var client=[];
        client['label']=v.name;
        client['value']=v.name;
        client['pic']=v.pic;
        client['id']=k;
        clients_ar.push(client);
    });

    $('.tables .new_bill .client').autocomplete({
        source: clients_ar,
        minLength: 0,
        select: function(event, ui) {
            var client_id=ui.item.id;
            var client_photo=ui.item.pic;
            ....................................
        }
    });
});
```